# WiX uninstall UI property not set

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to set a property via a WiX UI that is used at uninstall time.  I have done this successfully at install time.  Is there a difference in the sequence that is preventing me from getting the set property?  It seems that my property, REMOVEDATABASES is never set.  Or perhaps I need to publish it?  Here are some code snippets.  Any help is appreciated.

My property:

```
<Property Id="REMOVEDATABASES" Value="0" />
```

How I get to the dialog that allows the user to set the property:

```
<UI Id="WixUI_App">
  ...
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetConfigurationUnInstallDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
   ...
</UI>
```

My dialog that uses the property:

```
   <Dialog Id="SetConfigurationUnInstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Uninstall option">
    <Control Id="NextUninstall" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)"  >
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BackUninstall" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" >
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="CancelUninstall" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>

     ....

    <Control Id="UnistallDBLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="80" Height="14" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Unistall Database?" />
    <Control Id="RadioButtonGroupID" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="20" Y="58" Width="305" Height="100" Property="REMOVEDATABASES" Text="Remove Databases?" Default="no">
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="REMOVEDATABASES">
        <RadioButton Value="0" X="100" Y="0" Width="200" Height="10" Text="No" />
        <RadioButton Value="1" X="100" Y="20" Width="200" Height="10" Text="Yes" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
    </Control>
  </Dialog>
```

And, finally, my code that tries to use the property:

```
      <Component Id="cmpDatabaseUnInstall" Guid="B6D21CE5-9470-4D78-8760-E9AE04A91AB4"  KeyPath="yes">
    <Condition>REMOVEDATABASES = "1"</Condition>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="masterDB" Server="[SERVER]" Instance="[INSTANCE_NAME]" Database="master"
                   CreateOnInstall="no" ConfirmOverwrite="yes" DropOnUninstall="no" ContinueOnError="no"
                   CreateOnReinstall="no" CreateOnUninstall="no" DropOnInstall="no" DropOnReinstall="no">
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="DropAllDatabases"
                   SqlDb="masterDB" BinaryKey="DropAllDatabases"
                   ContinueOnError="yes" ExecuteOnInstall="no" ExecuteOnReinstall="no" ExecuteOnUninstall="yes"
                   Sequence="1"/>
  </Component>
```

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: FYI I merged your accounts together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties and Tables changed during an installation are not persisted.  You probably want to do the following:

[The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern)

Comment: BTW, be really careful with executing SQL scripts during an uninstall.  Makesure that if they fail you can still uninstall instead of being blocked.

Comment: I understand that properties are not persisted between installations.  I also understand how to save them to the registry.  But, that is not what I am doing here.

I am prompting the user the uninstall question ***during*** the uninstall process.  I am doing this with a Radio Group.  The radio group is using a public property, REMOVEDATABASES.  Later, in the same uninstall, I am trying to use that property to decide whether or not to run a script.  But, the public property never seems to be set.  Any idea why?

I do something similar during the install (i.e. ask the DB server name and inst

Comment: MSI doesn't support UI during an uninstall through Add/Remove Programs.  Removes never have UI beyond the initial yes/no confirmation.  The only way to get some kind of UI is to disable Remove and only enable Change.   Then when they select Remove prompt your question and move along.

Comment: Also make sure that when you harvest properties and prompt them in the UI that you have the write scheduling and conditions so that your two inputs don't step on each other.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead. If the blog post is available under an other URL, it would be useful to add it here or to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your property marked [Secure](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_property.htm) (i.e. listed in [SecureCustomProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))? If not, its value may not make it to the execute sequence. Searching the log for something like `Ignoring disallowed property` should confirm or deny this.